# minimum-stability issue when trying to install package

Tags: php, package, composer-php

I created a package and in that composer.json file I do not declare minimum-stability and therefor defaults to `stable`.

In another project I want to install this package with `composer require --dev my/package`. The composer.json in this file also has no minimum-stability so it should also default to `stable`.

However, I keep running into the error: `Could not find a version of package my/package matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.`

What am I missing here? My project wants packages with a minimum stability of `stable`, my package is `stable`, yet no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to delete this for being dumb, but I did use the search and didn't find anything. However, my/package only had a master branch and that was the issue. I added a tag(v1.0) and then it worked fine.